# import csv file to mysql remote server using mysqlimport

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, mysqlimport, csv-import

I have 4 csv files that I want to import into my AWS mysql database.

I am trying to use the following command from a windows machine:

```
"C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.7\bin\mysqlimport.exe" -h myhostname.amazonaws.com -P 3306 -u admin -pmypassword --local --fields-terminated-by=, --lines-terminated-by="\r\n" ticketsdb tickets "Data_2014_1.csv"
```

The response that I get is this:

```
mysqlimport: [Warning] Using a password on the command line interface can be insecure.
mysqlimport: Error: 2, File 'tickets' not found (Errcode: 2 - No such file or directory), when using table: tickets
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Do you actually have a file named "tickets" that you are trying to import? It sort of looks like you are trying to pass in a table name. Based on [the documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/mysqlimport.html), I think you need to rename `Data_2014_1.csv` to `tickets.csv` and then run the following command:

`"C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.7\bin\mysqlimport.exe" -h myhostname.amazonaws.com -P 3306 -u admin -pmypassword --local --fields-terminated-by=, --lines-terminated-by="\r\n" ticketsdb tickets.csv`

Comment: When I execute that I get the following

mysqlimport: [Warning] Using a password on the command line interface can be insecure.
mysqlimport: Error: 1146, Table 'ticketsdb.Data_2014_1' doesn't exist, when using table: Data_2014_1

Comment: If that's the error message then you didn't run the command I gave you. Data_2014_1 shouldn't be in there anymore.

Comment: Hey Mark,
Now I got what you were saying, I renamed it and now it worked, I guess I will have to rename the 4 files back and forth.
Any better way to import multiple files?

Comment: The documentation specifically says that it uses the filename as the table name. So if the files are all for the same table you would need to rename the files one at a time, or combine them somehow.